# VBA Text To Colums + Loop Structure

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm working on a macro to do the following: 
In column "W" I have a description as xxx_yyy_zzz, I want to bring that information,  separated by "_ " to different columns.

As per the code below, I've been able to do that for one line.

Step by Step what I'm trying to do is:

1) Copy cell on column W (I'll use cell "W2" for this example)

2) Go to Column B and paste it using TextToColums (delimited, the criteria would be the "_"):

B2 = xxx

C2 = yyy

D2 = zzz

3)Go back to colum W and do the same process for the next cell.(W3)

4) Do that Until the following cell on column W is blank.

5)PS: If cell on column B is not blank (has been previously populated), go back to the following cell on column W and do the same process.

My main problem is with the "Destination" (B6 in this case) that will vary each time I move from one line to another.

```
Sub Macro4()


    Range("W6").Select
    Selection.Copy

    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -21).Value = "" Then

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B6"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="_", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, _
        1), Array(6, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


      Else

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If



End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a slightly different approach, which loops through each cell in column W. I'm assuming that if B already contains something, you don't want anything done.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Long, v As Variant

For r = 1 To Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Len(Cells(r, "W")) > 0 Then
        If Len(Cells(r, "B")) = 0 Then
            v = Split(Cells(r, "W"), "_")
            Cells(r, "B").Resize(, UBound(v) + 1).Value = v
        End If
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: It Works like magic!!
Thank you so much for the quick answer!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the whole column in one action (unless you literally need to check each cell for some reason).

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("W6:W" & lastRow)
    .TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B6"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="_", _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End With
```